# Getting user information in a middleware and injecting it

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have JWT authentication in my .NET Core 2.2 API. When the user creates a new entity, I need to get his information (username and timezone set in the application) in order to audit the entity.

The point is, I don't want to add all of this in the Claims (there's some other properties as well) of my JWT and have it passing back and forth, and keeping it up to date when some user preference changes. So I rather put only my User's id on the Claims and upon receiveing his request I can then query my database / cache / whatever in order to get his full information.

What I thought of doing is create a Middleware that would process the request in order to get the user information and make it available as a Service (`UserInfo` for instance),  so I could get it in my DbContext and use it much like I can do with the `HttpContext`:

```
var ctx = this.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
```

(I'm using `DbContextPool`, that's why I get the service like that and don't inject it).

I'm not so familiar with the middlewares, but is that a way that my middleware would somehow make available the `UserInfo` so I could get it in my `DbContext` just like I can do with the `HttpContext`?